# Capturing Iframe data into image(png) in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, angular7

I have HTML content with Script tags in it that I am loading inside an iframe(Since I'm not able to process it in a normal angular HTML file as it has Head, Style, and Body tags altogether). I need to capture this Iframe content and save it as a Png format Image. I have tried several libraries like dom-to-image, html2canvas, etc but failed to capture the content inside an Iframe. Can anyone help me out with some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately there is no way to access the content of an cross-origin Iframes via HTML rendering libraries.

but Google Chrome recently introduced an ability to capture from a specific region of page which is called **Region Capture**.
this ability is embedded in *chrome version **104 and above***.

with this ability you can capture anything in a page include cross-origin iframes.

[see demo and examples](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/web-platform/region-capture/)